# Fetch until response data length is 0

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, axios, fetch

so I have this working fetch I wanted to know if I could improve it more so it will be faster, so the api only allows a limit of 100 items to return per call, and has a skipQ to skip a number so we could skip the previous responses and not get duplication  - so what I did was do a while loop until the response from one of the fields (dataCount) returns 0. Thoughts on improving and other alternatives?

```
        const fetchUsers = async () => {
        let d = 1
        let skip = 0
           while (d !== 0) {
              const response = await axios.post(`${URI}, {limit: '100', skipQ: skip}`)
                 skip += 100
                   if(response.data.dataCount === 0) {
                       d = response.data.dataCount
                   }
                   setUsers(prev => [...prev, response.data].flat())
                   } else {
                   navigate('/')
                   }
          }
        fetchUsers()
```

this function is inside a useEffect hhok

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing backtick (`\``) at the moment after `\`${URI}`

Comment: It depends on the API endpoint and it's restrictions.

Comment: But do you think what I did is passable?

Comment: @user3352042 "passable"? like *"acceptable"*? Or did you mean *"possible"*?

Comment: "acceptable" in other terms haha "passable" just good enough

Comment: I don't know, does it work? The basic approach is OK, but your curly braces don't seem to match and I don't think `\`${URI}, {limit: '100', skipQ: skip}\`` is correct. I don't think that this object belongs like that in the URI.